# Why aren't my htmlspecialchars and str_replace not working?

Tags: php

For my example, please visit http://jflaugher.mystudentsite.net/cmweb241/cmweb241_lab2.html

I am just needing the htmlspecialchars to work and the str_replace function to remove double and single quotes.  Why isn't this working for me?  I am very new to PHP :/

```
 <?php
  $username = str_replace(array("'", "\""), "", htmlspecialchars($_POST['username']));
  $password = str_replace(array("'", "\""), "", htmlspecialchars($_POST['password']));
  $comment = str_replace(array("'", "\""), "", htmlspecialchars($_POST['comment']));

  echo " <p>Your Username is: $username . </p>";
  echo " <p>Your Password is: $password . </p>";
  echo " <p>Your Comment was: $comment . </p>";

?>
```

Comment: `htmlspecialchars` - convert single & double quote to htmlentities, so, you won't have any matches.

Comment: Do it in the other order. Remove the quotes first, then do htmlspecialchars.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use it in reverse order as specified by **Alex Lunix**

```
$username = htmlspecialchars(str_replace(array("'", "\""), "", $_POST['username']));
```

Comment: +1 For seeing my name in an answer. (And for it being correct.)

Comment: @AlexLunix As a advice, if you know the answer then post it as answer,just don't comment it. :)

Comment: I felt it was too short of an answer and was being lazy :p Maybe next time though, I like rep as much as anybody.

Comment: @Alex Sorry I stepped away from my computer for a minute.  I am not getting the htmlspecialchars to work still.  When I insert an ampersand for example, the entity does not show up, but instead the ampersand.  The quotes don't show up though!

Comment: You can visit this link to see what I am talking about.    http://jflaugher.mystudentsite.net/cmweb241/cmweb241_lab2.html                I inserted the above snippet and am still getting the HTML entity characters, instead of its entity.

Comment: @JeremyFlaugher The symbols will display, but if you look at the source it should appear as &amp; Try some html tags instead to see that they don't get interpreted as html by the browser. For example, pretend you're trying to inject an img tag and see that it fails.

Comment: @ALEXLunix  Yep you are right!  Thank you.  I will give you + rep.   I need the entity to show up when echoed, and not the html character.  For example, when they insert '&', I need echoed back '&amp;

Comment: @JeremyFlaugher It's not my answer, so I won't get the rep, but it IS correct, so you should choose it. To get what you want you need to do htmlspecialchars *twice*

Comment: @AlexLunix  Thank you for your help and time.  It is people like yourself that helps us NOOBS find our way.  I +1'd this answer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24199/discussion-between-jeremy-flaugher-and-alex-lunix)

Answer (score 1):

The previous answer is correct.

You apply first htmlspecialchars function. It converts every double quote to &quot; and every single quote to &#039;. These special characters are shown in a web browser as double and single quotes respectively.

You should apply first str_replace. The code below is correct:

```
<?php
foreach(array('comment', 'password', 'username') as $key) {
    $$key = empty($_POST[$key]) ? null : htmlspecialchars(str_replace(array("'", '"'), '', $_POST[$key]));
    echo " <p>Your " . $key. " is: " . $$key . "</p>";
}
?>
```

Comment: This seems incredibly unnecessary for 3 values, sure it might make sense for more, but there aren't more... Readability over optimization. Although one thing you have that he should add is validation that the field is set.